# C++ - static meaning for variables in global scope

Tags: c++

What is the significance of defining a variable as static when you define it in the global scope? Aren't global variables "static" anyway?

i.e: is there any difference between this code? :

```
int var1 = 0;
int main()
{
    return var1;
}

static int var1 = 0;
int main()
{
    return var1;
}
```

I know that the static variable will not be accessible from any other translation unit, but that's not really what I'm concerned with.

Comment: what are you concerned with then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Aren't global variables "static" anyway?

Global variables are indeed placed in static memory. However, they are global in all translation units, so linker sees their names.

> is there any difference between this code? [...]

If you decide to link your first code with another translation unit that has `var1`, you are going to get a link error. Your second code would compile correctly, even if `var1` in the other translation unit is global.

> I know that the static variable will not be accessible from any other translation unit, but that's not really what I'm concerned with.

Internal or external scope is the only difference. One could argue that it is a misuse of the keyword `static`, but that is the way it is in the C standard.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the translation unit visibility that you already mention, there is no difference.